# Reading the device tree for ide disks

Tags: solaris, device-tree

On Solaris I know disk are `c0d0p0` or `c0d0s0` for ide, `c1t1d1s0` for scsi. I see there are links on pci devices,for example:

```
 ls -lh /dev/dsk/c0d0s7
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          50 ago  1 22:53 /dev/dsk/c0d0s7 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1,1/ide@0/cmdk@0,0:h
```

Someone know what does it mean `pci@0,0/pci-ide@1,1/ide@0/cmdk@0,0:h`?

I think `pci0,0` is pci bus, `pci-ide@1,1` is first controller. `ide,ide@0` the master disk?

And `cmdk@'0,0h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmdk@0,0:h` is the driver instance for a disk.  Per the [Solaris documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1475/cmdk-7d.html):

> The cmdk device driver is a common interface to various disk devices.
>   The driver supports magnetic fixed disks and magnetic removable disks.